# How to properly "override" some property from TextStyle

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my own style:

```
final myStyle =  GoogleFonts.roboto(
    height: 1.2,
    color: Colors.black54,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    fontSize: 16
);
```

I want to use it later in two TextWidget, but with different FontWeight property, so I thought about using copyWith method like this:

```
   Text(
                  "myText",
                  style: myStyle.copyWith(fontWeight:FontWeight.w400 ),
                ),
```

But it's not working. Text is not bolded (by FontWeight.w400)

Comment: weight 400 is usually not bolded. Try w700

Comment: The default value is 400, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontWeight-class.html for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value of fonts is `w400` already so it will look as it is not working but it is, so I suggest you to try a different `FontWeight` so you can see the difference. By the way you are `overriding` it properly already.